# How to add another action to an action in C#?

Tags: c#, delegates

Why this code will print only "A" and "B", but not "C" ?

```cs
Action act = null;
act += () => MessageLog.Message("A");
act += () => MessageLog.Message("B");
Action<Action> add = a => a += () => MessageLog.Message("C");
add(act);
act.Invoke();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Delegates are immutable. The `+=` operator creates a *new* delegate with an invocation list consisting of the invocation list from the left side, followed by the invocation list from the right hand side of the operator. It then stores a reference to that delegate in the variable on the left hand side. So

```cs
act += () => MessageLog.Message("A");
```

is equivalent to

```
act = act + (Action) (() => MessageLog.Message("A"));
```

which is in turn equivalent to:

```cs
act = (Action) Delegate.Combine(act, (Action) (() => MessageLog.Message("A"));
```

So, now we can come to your `add` delegate. This lambda expression:

```cs
a => a += () => MessageLog.Message("C");
```

... modifies the parameter `a` to refer to the newly combined delegate... and then ignores it.

Instead, you need to *return* the combined delegate (so change `add` to be a `Func<Action, Action>`) and then use the return value when you invoke `add`:

```cs
Action act = null;
act += () => MessageLog.Message("A");
act += () => MessageLog.Message("B");
Func<Action, Action> add = a => a + () => MessageLog.Message("C");
act = add(act);
act.Invoke();
```

Comment: So, in comparison, this is just like passing an "int" to a function and inside, adding some value to that "int"? Anyway all that helped me and as always, I get stuck on the simplest of things. Thanks!

Comment: @krokots: Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 4):

As you probably know, `A += B` is just shorthand for `A = A + B`, so your `add` delegate is really just:

```
a => a = a + () => MessageLog.Message("C")
```

The `+` creates the combined delegate `a + () => MessageLog.Message("C")`, and `=` assigns it back to `a`. Notice how you are just reassigning the parameter `a`, and now it should be clear that this [doesn't change the variable that is passed in (`act`) at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29606475/c-sharp-pass-by-value-vs-pass-by-reference).

Other than returning the combined delegate, you can also pass `act` by reference:

```
delegate void ByRefAction<T>(ref T parameter);

...

    Action act = null;
    act += () => Console.WriteLine("A");
    act += () => Console.WriteLine("B");
    ByRefAction<Action> add = (ref Action a) => a += () => Console.WriteLine("C");
    add(ref act);
    act.Invoke();
```